# Cron Scheduling bad username

Tags: linux, shell, cron

My crontab isn't running. After checking the syslog I am getting the following errors:

```
Dec  7 18:57:01 raspberrypi cron[334]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/crontab
Dec  7 18:57:01 raspberrypi cron[334]: (*system*crontab) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

I'm trying to schedule a cron task, and it keeps giving me a bad username error... i've tried both:

```
57 13 * * * pi /home/pi/Desktop/shell.sh
```

and

```
57 13 * * * root /home/pi/Desktop/shell.sh
```

and they're both coming back invalid, what am i missing?

Comment: have you tried to reload the cron daemon after changing the file?

Answer (score 1):

You might have gotten some unintended control characters when editing your crontab. `cat -v` on your crontab to check. Always make sure to edit your crontab with `crontab -e`.